# Odd string parsing with double colons in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I've stumbled upon something odd with Perl string parsing. Here's an example:

```
$word = "hello";
$test1 = "colon:values::$word:test";
$test2 = "colon:values::$word::test";

// test1 prints: "colon:values::hello:test"
// test2 prints: "colon:values::"
```

So if Perl sees a double colon after a variable in a string, it will (I assume) think you're trying to use a package name. I guess it's trying to load "Hello::test" and not finding anything - hence the early termination of the string.

Is this normal? I find it pretty counter-intuitive. I was able to work around it by escaping the first colon like so:

```
$works = "colon:values::$word\::test";
```

Is this a bug or am I completely missing something obvious?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. This would have said you were printing undefined variable `$word::test`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While that works, a more widespread way to handle the case is to disambiguate the name of your variable with braces:

```
perl -E "my $word = 'red'; say qq|colon::values::${word}::test|"
colon::values::red::test
```

This is documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors):

> As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces to
>   disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores). You
>   must also do this when interpolating a variable into a string to
>   separate the variable name from a following double-colon or an
>   apostrophe, since these would be otherwise treated as a package
>   separator:
>
> ```
> $who = "Larry";
> print PASSWD "${who}::0:0:Superuser:/:/bin/perl\n";
> print "We use ${who}speak when ${who}'s here.\n";
> ```
>
> Without the braces, Perl would have looked for a `$whospeak`, a
>   `$who::0`, and a `$who's` variable. The last two would be the `$0` and
>   the `$s` variables in the (presumably) non-existent package `who`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because it's trying to look up `$word::test` as a variable name. As you've correctly deduced, the package separator `::` is part of the name, but it's not going to follow the value of `$word` because it's not being used as a symbolic reference here (that requires more syntax).

Oesor's solution will solve your problem - the general way to fix this kind of issue is to use `${identifier}` syntax. Basically use it any time you're interpolating a variable into a string and you need to follow it with something that's a valid identifier character or related symbol (i.e. `::`).

Comment: or the older form of ::, \`

Comment: Yes that one catches a lot of people out.

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses namespaces for variable names, and Perl when Perl sees `::` or a `'`, it assumes what's before is a package (i.e. namespace) name. It is similar to this *error*:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    # You're using these? Aren't you?

my $foo = "bar"
print "The magic word is $foo_for_you\n";
```

Since the underscore is a valid character for variable names, Perl assumes that you want the variable `$foo_for_you` and not `$foo` with `_for_you` appended to the value. So, would you consider this a *bug* or a *feature*? Is it any difference from this:

```
print "The magic word is $foobar\n";   # Whoops! my variable is $foo.
```

The way to get around this is to make it absolutely clear that `$foo` is your variable:

```
print "The magic word is " . $foo . "_for_you\n";
printf "The magic word is %s_for_you\n", $foo;
print "The magic word is ${foo}_for_you\n";
```

The same issue if you had `$foo::for::you` (or `$foo'for'you`) In this case, Perl is looking for a variable called `$you` in the namespace `foo::for`. As you can imagine, you can use similar solutions:

```
print "The magic word is " . $foo . "::for::you\n";
printf "The magic word is %d::for::you\n", $foo;
print "The magic word is ${foo}::for::you\n";
```

Namespaces are used to help keep variables in Perl modules from modifying variables in your program. Imagine calling a function in a Perl package, and suddenly discovering that a variable you were using in your program was changed.

Take a look at [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and you can see variables with the package namespace attached to them (`$File::Find::name` and `$File::Find::dir` are two examples).